# Как изменить locale.getpreferredencoding() кодировку US-ASCII на UTF-8 в Python 3.x?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, utf-8, unicode

При запуске программы из консоли(Linux) получаю ошибку

> Unicodeencodeerror ascii codec can't encode characters in position 0-7

Я начал искать ошибку. Оказалось, что при запуске программы из консоли функция `locale.getpreferredencoding()` выдает: `US-ASCII`
Для нормального decod'a текста нужна `UTF-8`, однако функции `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` в *Python 3* нет.

Вопрос: Как изменить кодировку?

Comment: Вы таки где конкретно эту ошибку получаете-то?

Comment: Вы пробовали  добавить первой строкой в файлик с пайтоном`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- `  ?

Comment: @nick_gabpe Конечно, это прописано в самом начале файла.

Comment: @andreymal Когда я запускаю программу из консоли(Linux) функция locale.getpreferredencoding()  возвращает "US-ASCII" из-за этого программа крашится, так как не может декодировать кириллицу.

Comment: @IvanProvorov программы бывают разные, большие и маленькие, простые и сложные, и такая ошибка может получиться в любом их месте, так вы таки где конкретно эту ошибку получаете-то?

Comment: @andreymal Уже неважно, проблема решена.

Comment: @Ivan Provorov напишите пожалуйста, как именно вы решили проблему. Это важно для понимания сути.